# $p$-adic metric space $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider a $\mathbb{Z}$ endowed with the metric $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$ and $d(x,y)=997^{-n}$ if $x\not=y$, where $n$ is the largest integer such that $997^n$ divide $y-x$.

- Is $\mathbb{Z}$ closed and bounded?
- An infinite subset exists no limit points?

I turned: We know that there existe a metric space $(X,d)$ has a closed and bounded set that is not compact. Let $X=\{1/n\;|\;n\in \mathbb{N}$} and discrete metric $d:X\times X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined for all $x,y\in X$ by $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$ and $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\not =y$ only then the $X$ set is known closed and bounded set. In the given problem:
\begin{align}\tag{1}
    d(x,y)=\begin{cases}
0 &\mbox{ if }x=y
\\
997^{-n} &\mbox{ if }x\not=y
\end{cases}
\end{align}

where $n$ is the largest integer such that $997^n$ divide $y-x$.

Eq. (1) is approximated as:
\begin{align}\tag{2}
    d(x,y)=\begin{cases}
0 &\mbox{ if }x=y
\\
1 &\mbox{ if }x\not=y
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Therefore, using that there existe a metric space $(X,d)$ has a closed and bounded set that is not compact. We can say that the given set $\mathbb{Z}$ which endowed with the metric is closed and bounded.

Is this procedure correct?

On the other hand, can we construct an infinite set no limit points?

Comment: How about $1, 997, 997^2, 997^3, ...?$

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number, there is a ring of $p$-adic integers, in this case take the special prime $p=997$. Please give a better shape to the second question...

Comment: $997^n \to 0$ in this metric.

Comment: @GEdgar, this is second question? 
I think that means that it converges to 0?

Comment: the finite sum $s_n=1+997^2+997^4+\dots+997^{2n}$, so the set $S=\{s_n\;|\;n\in \mathbb{N} \}$ is infinite. But has no limit points?

Comment: That is good.  It shows that $\mathbb Z$ is not complete in this metric. Series $\sum 997^{2n}$ should converge to $1/(1-997^2)$ which is not in $\mathbb Z$ (but is a $p$-adic integer).